# How to use beautifulsoup4 to find <p> with no class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently doing a project to improve my python knowledge. It's an attempt to use `beautifulsoup` to find specific data being held in `<p>` with no class from the website [text](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1588/001/)

I have pasted the modules I am using as well as the section of code that I'm having trouble fixing at the bottom.

[image: snip of text I'm trying to parse]
Any help is appreciated!

[image: snip of html]

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

mitigation = []

for id in id_list:
    page = requests.get(f"https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/{id2}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    paragraph = soup.find('p', class_ = '')
    status_code = page.status_code
    mitigation.append(paragraph)
```

I have attempted to use:

```py
paragraph = soup.select('p')[4].text
```

instead of:

```py
paragraph = soup.find('p', class_ = '')
```

in order to find the correct `<p>`

Comment: Maybe try `class_=None`?

Comment: Or `soup.select('p[class=""]')`

Comment: Neither work. This biggest issue is there are about 15 different <p> and there is no class to make a distinction between them.

Comment: You can just use `findall('p')`, loop over them, and look for the one with no class.

Comment: All <p> have no class brother

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. I thought you wanted to find the one with no class, distinguishing it from the rest.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarification. The structure of the html on the website seems...unintuitive. There are a varying amount of <p> tags within each URL (often above 15) and none of them have a class associated with them. I'm essentially trying to find the needle in the haystack and I believe the response using regex could possibly work. The issue is that the <p> tag I'm looking for has no identifiable features to separate it from the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The question could do with a little more clarity in order to provide a good and holistic approach to a solution, which is why it is only dealt with selectively here.*

In my view, @Barmar's comments would have been correct approaches to solving the problem, given the focus of the question.

However, in order to pick up on a specific content, let's break away from the `<p>` without a class and look at the bigger picture. What other context can we use to localise this specific content? Adapt your selection so that you orientate yourself on the HTML structure, unique and less dynamic attributes.

You are looking for mitigations, simply select this area using an `id` and proceed from there with the next steps - used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here for chaining:

```
soup.select_one('#mitigations + div table p')
```

If you need it from multiple rows use `select()` over `select_one()` and iterate over its resultset.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/').text)

mitigation = []

for id in ['T1588/001/','T1129/']:
    page = requests.get(f"https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/{id}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    paragraph = soup.select_one('#mitigations + div table p')
    mitigation.append(paragraph.text)

mitigation
```

---

```
['This technique cannot be easily mitigated with preventive controls since it is based on behaviors performed outside of the scope of enterprise defenses and controls.','Identify and block potentially malicious software executed through this technique by using application control tools capable of preventing unknown modules from being loaded.']
```

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarification. I'm going to take some time to understand the structure of the html in this website. I'm finding that as I've looked through it it seems like a very unintuitive way to create a layout (maybe I'm wrong here). So this <p> tag I'm looking for sits inside a <td> tag. There are 3 total <td> tags sitting inside the <tr> tag. Is there a way to use regex to find a known length letter followed by four numbers (M[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) that is consistently the first <td> tag, and then pull the data from a <p> tag sitting inside of the third <td> tag?

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus -  Please keep in mind to create a [mcve] and provide an example of the expected result, so that everybody could reproduce your issue and get an idea of your goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for id in id_list:
    page = requests.get(f"https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/{id2}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    specific_header = soup.find('h2', text=re.compile('header To be searched'))
    if specific_header:
        paragraph = specific_header.find_next('p')
        mitigation.append(paragraph.text if paragraph else None)
    else:
        mitigation.append(None)
```

Here the header to be searched can either be a regex or a text and this should work.

Comment: I am going to give this a shot. Looks like regex might be the answer. Thank you.